# PHP - reorder array if it contains certain values and those arrays are in a certain order

Tags: php, arrays, sorting

I have an array which looks something like this...

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [region_id] => 1
            [region_content] => news2
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [region_id] => 2
            [region_content] => something_else
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [region_id] => 3
            [region_content] => news
        )

)
```

I need to do a few things with it...

Check to see whether the array contains both `news` and `news2` and if so switch their positions if news2 appears before news.

So the resulting array would look like this:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [region_id] => 1
            [region_content] => news
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [region_id] => 2
            [region_content] => something_else
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [region_id] => 3
            [region_content] => news2
        )

)
```

So I need some help with how to check the array and then how to reorder it.

Comment: Have you tried anything? Give an example code

Comment: If i'm honest, my brain is fried and I can't think where to start (not an excuse, I know).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is far from an efficient way to do it or a best practice, but for purpose of explanation:

```
<?php
$collection = [
    [
        'region_id' => 1,
        'region_content' => 'news2'
    ],
    [
        'region_id' => 2,
        'region_content' => 'something else'
    ],
    [
        'region_id' => 3,
        'region_content' => 'news'
    ],
];

$occurrences = 0;
$final = '';
foreach ($collection as $sub) {
    if (in_array($sub['region_content'], ['news', 'news2'])) {
        $occurrences++;
        $final = $sub['region_content'];
    }
}

$toSwitch = ($occurrences == 2) && $final == 'news';

if ($toSwitch) {
    foreach ($collection as &$sub) {
        if ($sub['region_content'] == 'news2') $sub['region_content'] = 'news';
        elseif ($sub['region_content'] == 'news') $sub['region_content'] = 'news2';
    }
}

var_dump($collection);
```

If `region_content` is either `news` or `news2` we are incrementing the occurrences variables. As we are expecting exactly 2 occurrences - `news` and `news2` and as well we are checking if `news2` is first. So if `final` variables is populated with `news` we are sure that `news2` were before than.

The final result of if Occurrences == 2 and `news2` is first is the boolean representation if we need to switch their positions.

Switching the position here is nothing different than just changing the value. As it is string we just hardcoded it. If it is some nested collection, you can extract its value in the first iteration.

```
The result of the dump is:

array (size=3)
  0 => 
    array (size=2)
      'region_id' => int 1
      'region_content' => string 'news' (length=4)
  1 => 
    array (size=2)
      'region_id' => int 2
      'region_content' => string 'something else' (length=14)
  2 => &
    array (size=2)
      'region_id' => int 3
      'region_content' => string 'news2' (length=5)
```

Answer (score 0):

This should do what you're asking:

```
// Check if both news and news2 exist and make sure news come before news2
function checkNewsAndSwap($array)
{
    // Obtain the indexes
    $indexes = [];
    foreach($array as $i => $v) {
        if($v['region_content'] == 'news') {
            $indexes[1] = $i;
        }
        elseif($v['region_content'] == 'news2') {
            $indexes[2] = $i;
        }
    }

    // Both news and news2 exist
    if(isset($indexes[1]) && isset($indexes[2])) {
        if($indexes[2] < $indexes[1]) {// If news comes after news2
            // Swap them!
            $tmp = $array[$indexes[1]]['region_content'];
            $array[$indexes[1]]['region_content'] = $array[$indexes[2]]['region_content'];
            $array[$indexes[2]]['region_content'] = $tmp;
        }
    }

    return $array;
}
```

Test code and results are here: http://pastie.org/9637389

Comment: Almost, but I don't want to switch the whole subarray, just the region_content values.

Comment: Anyways, I've updated my code (it was just a matter of adding ['region_content'] to a couple of lines). My solution is still far more efficient than the accepted answer, as it loops the array just once. @Tom